# C programming - assign a struct member variable to a char *

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a variable declared as `const char * server = NULL;`

This variable is assigned a value when the user passes the IP address of a server as a command line argument to the C program using the code below. For example, running `./cprogram -h 10.4.0.01`

```
opt = 1;
while (opt < argc)
{
    if (argv[opt] == NULL    ||
        argv[opt][0] != '-'  ||
        argv[opt][2] != 0)
    {
        print_usage();
        return 0;
    }

    switch (argv[opt][1])
    {
        case 'h':
            opt++;
            if (opt >= argc)
            {
                print_usage();
                return 0;
            }
            server = argv[opt];
            break;
    }
```

I am removing the need to pass command line arguments from the program and putting the values in an .ini file.

I now read an .ini file at the start of the program and store the values in a struct.

```
struct lwm2m_object {
    char clientname[LG_BUF];
    char ipv4[LG_BUF];
    char server[LG_BUF];
};
```

In the correct way to assign the struct member variable `server` to the variable `const char * server` using this

```
server = &(lwm2m.server);
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: You need to use `strcpy` (or `strncpy`) to assign the C strings in your struct.

Comment: ``C`` and ``C++`` are different languages. You shouldn't use the tag together (unless your question is about interfacing ``C`` with ``C++``).

Answer (score 1):

The assignment is not correct. The correct assignment is

```
server = lwm2m.server;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
server = &(lwm2m.server);
```

is **doubly wrong**. First, the string you intend to copy is `lwm2m.server` -- remember that an array decays to a pointer. So, better is

```
server = lwm2m.server;    // Still dangerous
```

But this merely copies the pointer to the data (**shallow copy**). If the `lwm2m_object` `lwm2m` goes out of scope, then the associated string `lwm2m_object::server` is freed and may be re-used. In other words, your copy in `server` then becomes a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

If you **know** that `lwm2m` survives `server` (so that there is no danger of getting a dangling pointer), then the shallow copy is okay (and preferable). Otherwise, you must make a deep copy, using [`strcpyn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy):

```
const char server[LG_BUF];
strcpyn(server, lwm2m.server, LG_BUF);
```